# How to print a dict in a python file with python script

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, utf-8

I need to print in a python file a dict with another python scripts. How can i do this??

I have a python file "languages.py" that i created with a single dict.
From this file i export a csv file with pandas library. After i import from csv file the dict and print in the same but new languages.py file when i try to use in another file by an import of language.py file doesn't work.

Sorry for my english

```
def write_import_language(path, name):
    
    # Creo indicazione file da importare
    directory = f'{path}/{name}.csv'

    LogFile.add_row(f'Importazione lingue richiesta: file = {directory}', top_empty_line=1)
    print(f'Importazione lingue richiesta: file = {directory}')

    try:
        # Leggo dataframe dal file excel
        df = pd.read_csv(directory)
        print(df)

        # Salvo il file language.py come language_old.py
        with  open(f'{LANGUAGE_DICT_DIR}\\languages.py', "r") as f:
            old_file = f.read()
        #print(old_file)
        with open(f'{LANGUAGE_DICT_DIR}\\languages_old.py', 'w') as f:
            f.write(old_file)

        # Scrivo nuovo file in base a dataframe
        dictionary = create_language_file_from_import(df)
        #lines_to_write = Import.structured_dict_imported(dictionary)
        #print(lines_to_write)
        with open(f'{LANGUAGE_DICT_DIR}\\languages.py', 'w') as f:
            f.write(dictionary)
            # for line in lines_to_write:
            #     f.write(f'{line}\n')

        # Importazione riuscita
        LogFile.add_row(f'Importazione lingue riuscita {dictionary}', bottom_empty_line=1)
        print(f'Importazione riuscita')

        # Ristampo templates
        #init_HTML_templates()

    except Exception as e:
        LogFile.add_row(f'Importazione lingue non riuscita', bottom_empty_line=1)
        print(f'Importazione non riuscita:\n{e}')
```

I try this and it works, but when i try to use the dict in the new file languages.py created by this scripts, it doesn't work an this is the error:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 139: invalid start byte

I don't understand why!

Comment: did you try specifying the `encoding='utf8'` when you `open` the file?

Comment: While I think the above comment will fix the problem, frankly, what you are trying to do here seems very much like a bad idea. what is `dictionary`? Please **always** provide a [mcve]